# How to implement Inter-Process Communication(IPC) at the local machine without parent-child model?

Tags: c#, ipc

I'm trying to exchange some small data between my two C# apps. This two apps located at the same PC, so all exchange happens inside this machine. At first, I thought maybe to use sockets for it, cause I had some small experience with it, but then I read some articles that said that it's not the best practice for it, cause all exchange happens at the same local machine, so don't need to use network solutions for such task.

And then I learned about anonymous pipes. At first from descriptions and examples it's looks liked the best for my case. But then turns out that this is all about parent-child model, so one(parent) app have to open another one(child) and pass data about pipe through constructor of child app. And this is not fit for my case, cause I want that my two apps would be totally independent, like they could close anytime separately, and then reopen again any time and after that continue data exchanging.

So how do you think, what would be the best for my case? Should I back to sockets? Or maybe anonymous pipes is also not always about parent-child model and maybe I just missed something?

Comment: What is the .net you're targeting, full or core (.net 5)?

You could do sockets, or HTTP, or you could try a net pipe using WCF, a shared file, registry, database, service broker, redis, and many many other things. The key questions are how complex does it need to be, how realtime, how reliable and how much overhead do you care about?

Comment: Just because you have 2 independent app, doesn't mean you cant have a child parent relationship. Who cares if they can close independently.

Comment: Anyway, to know the best solution, we need to know what problem you are trying to solve. There is nothing stopping you from trying a couple

Comment: @zaitsman I guess it's .NET framework 4.6. Yeah, I want to exchange data in realtime, but delaying around 1 -2 seconds is okay. I think it shouldn't be so complexed, one app will just send to another one 5digit numbers with totally random time period, so sometime it can be no messages at all, sometime around 7-10 numbers can came at the same time.

Comment: @00110001 sorry, I didn't fully get about parent-child relationships. So no matter when I opened and closed this two apps windows I can use anonymnous pipes? Just all examples I find in internet was like: parent app open child app. Do you have example of opposite? I would really appreciate it.